# Fullcalendar updateEvent isn't rendering the event properly

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using `updateEvent` method to update an event on the fly in the week view.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'updateEvent', event);
```

It works fine If I'm updating the date of the event (It is moving fine across the allDay slots). But If I'm changing the start / end time of the existing event, I don't see the event after the `updateEvent` (which means the updated event is disappeared)

I see the event object in the console

```
start: Object, end: null, // For the old event. Object is moment, converted by fullcalendar
start: '2017-02-14T07:00:00', end: '2017-02-14T08:00:00' // Updated date and time
```

So, clearly I'm setting the date and time properly. I've no idea why it is not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

I tried removing the old event by using `removeEvents` and created a new event by calling the `renderEvents`. Still the same issue.

Then I tried removing all the properties starts with `_` from the event object and it worked when I removed the `source` object from the `fullcalendar's`.

> From the docs, `source` is automatically populated and it is the reference to the event source that this event came from.

So clearly, when we are updating the event, we have to remove the `source` property of the event otherwise it may still refer to the old one.

Here is my code.

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', oldEvent._id);
delete oldEvent._id;
delete oldEvent._allDay;
delete oldEvent._start;
delete oldEvent._end;
delete oldEvent.source;
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', oldEvent, true);
```